# Data level aggregation for price elasticity

Tags: regression, linear-model, elasticity

I have just started working on price elasticity and I have some fundamental question.

Question 1: I have daily price and sales data for a product, now if I want to calculate the price elasticity should I aggregate the data at a weekly or some other level or should I directly feed the data into a regression model.

Question 2: Now let's assume the data size is very large and I cannot run models on daily data which in this case leads me to aggregating the data at a weekly level. The questions is how do I aggregate the data which contains these scenarios:
1) There may be multiple price points within the week
2) One product may have same price for 2 weeks then its price change for another week and then the price reverts back to original in the next week.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: I have daily price and sales data for a product, now if I
>   want to calculate the price elasticity should I aggregate the data at
>   a weekly or some other level or should I directly feed the data into a
>   regression model.

I think you can do both ways: aggregate by days (but if price deviates inside a day you will loose some information), and aggregate by price while adjusting for the number of days the price was holding.

The later is better, to my mind, as you will see the clear dependence between price and volume. It should look this way:

price: 1.02; 1.03; 1.04; 1.05...
sales: 1.4M; 1.3M; 1.2M; 1.2M...

> Question 2: Now let's assume the data size is very large and I cannot
>   run models on daily data which in this case leads me to aggregating
>   the data at a weekly level.

Averaging the price on a daily basis will do the trick, but, again, with some loss of information.